# Cypress can't type() into contenteditable element

Tags: cypress

Context: I'm using cypress 10.11.0 and am trying to select an element on ck editor 5.

I have a div that has the contenteditable attribute set to true and am trying to type into it, but at run time the type fails and the error suggest that the div doesn't have the attribute at all, but even right before the type() call I can still see it in the developer window. Doesn't seem to be a problem with CK Editor since it's just html at this point.

Code:

```
const body =
        'div.ck-editor__editable[contenteditable="true"]';
cy.get(body)
.should('be.visible')
.click()
.focused()
.wait(10000) // Wait for 10 second to check attribute
.type('This is additional text', { force: true })
.type('{ctrl+a}');
```

Screenshot of the error:[image]

Comment: Were you able to solve this, seeing something very similar at our end

Comment: @andy_roddam I contacted the cypress team and they confirmed that it's a technical limitation of cypress when using ck_editor5. You either have to add the https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events library and use that (but it only works on chromium based browsers) or you have to use .setData() method which doesn't allow for actions like {enter} etc.
Issue covering this as well - https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/26155